# BinaryWriterWith7BitEncoding & BinaryReaderWith7BitEncoding

Tags: c#

Mr. Ayende wrote in his [latest blog post about an implementation of a queue](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/17/building-a-managed-persistent-transactional-queue.aspx). In the post he's using two magical files: BinaryWriterWith7BitEncoding & BinaryReaderWith7BitEncoding

`BinaryWriterWith7BitEncoding` can write both int and long? using the following method signatures: `void WriteBitEncodedNullableInt64(long? value)` & `void Write7BitEncodedInt(int value)`

and

`BinaryReaderWith7BitEncoding` can read the values written using the following method signatures: `long? ReadBitEncodedNullableInt64()` and `int Read7BitEncodedInt()`

So far I've only managed to find a way to read the 7BitEncodedInt:

```
protected int Read7BitEncodedInt()
{
    int value = 0;
    int byteval;
    int shift = 0;
    while(((byteval = ReadByte()) & 0x80) != 0)
    {
        value |= ((byteval & 0x7F) << shift);
        shift += 7;
    }
    return (value | (byteval << shift));
}
```

I'm not too good with byte shifting - does anybody know how to read and write the 7BitEncoded long? and write the int ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this is pretty much the same as what protobuf uses; those versions are a bit... "optimised", but I'll try to simplify. And for info, it makes writing a **lot** easier if you treat it as unsigned ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something like the write:

```
    static void Write7BitEncodedInt32(Stream dest, int value)
    {
        Write7BitEncodedUInt32(dest, (uint) value);
    }
    static void Write7BitEncodedUInt32(Stream dest, uint value)
    {
        if(value < 128) { dest.WriteByte((byte)value); return;}
        while(value != 0)
        {
            byte b = (byte) (value & 0x7F);
            value >>= 7; // since uint, we'll eventually run out of 1s
            if (value != 0) b |= 0x80; // and there's more
            dest.WriteByte(b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic!
Do you also have a solution to the 2nd part of the question with the nullable long?

Comment: @Tim - well, `long` is virtually identical; the only change is `ulong` instead of `uint` etc. With `Nullable<T>`, it comes down to "what do I write if it is null?" - only you can answer that.